# random sampling on random samples

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

I would like to understand if the sample distribution of the following approaches are the same or not.

Setup: population of size $N$, with binomial distribution. required sample size is $n$

Approach 1 (direct sample): randomly sample $n$ samples from population $N$ without replacement.

Approach 2 (sample from samples): randomly sample $k$ samples from population $N$ ($N>k>n$) without replacement, and then sample $n$ samples from the selected $k$ samples without replacement.

Questions:

1. will approach 1 and 2 produce the same sample distribution?
2. Can I use sample 2 to estimate mathematical properties of population $N$? For example, given accuracy of sample $n$, estimate the accuracy range of the population $N$?

Comment: I was wondering why you wanted to do the second approach. In the case of cluster sampling, one randomly picks sample sub-populations from the whole population, say towns or schools etc and then take a random sample from those. It is for convenience purposes as it is much easier to have a sample from one randomly selected sub-population than one made up of individuals spread all over the country. It is susceptible to some bias however. Your 2nd approach isn't quite the same so I'm wondering why you are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of ambiguity in your language, so let me make sure I have your intended meaning down: when you say, "randomly sample n samples from population," I think you mean, "randomly select n *objects* from population" instead. The distinction matters; are we collecting $n$ samples, or one sample consisting of $n$ objects?

Presuming it is indeed just one sample, then the two methods are equivalent. Either will produce a collection of $n$ objects from the population, and each collection of size $n$ has a $1 / \binom N n$ chance of being selected. For proof, you could just use a symmetry argument, or you could compute directly that in the second case the probability of a subgroup of size $n$ being selected is $$\frac{\binom{N-n}{k-n}}{\binom N k} \cdot \frac{1}{\binom k n} = \frac{(N-n)! \, k! \, (N-k)! \, n! \, (k-n)!}{(k-n)! \,(N-k)! \, N! \, k!} = \frac{1}{\binom N n}.$$

If you do mean that you're doing repeated samples, though, then whether it constitutes the same process as the approach 1 depends on how often you are selecting the superset of $k$ objects. If they are redrawn each time, then this process is indistinguishable from approach 1. But if the set of $k$ objects is fixed and repeated samples are taken from that smaller subset, then no, this process is not equivalent to approach 1.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for the explanation. Really helpful! I have a follow-up question.

Comment: What's on your mind?

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for the answer. Very helpful! I have another question. Will these two approaches still be the same under the following situation?

Situation: add filtering before sampling.
Approach 1: Filter population of size $N$ and have $Z$ objects left. $n$ objects are randomly selected from $Z$. 
Approach 2: randomly select $k$ objects out of $N$ objects, apply same filter on these $k$ objects. $Z'$ objects left after filtering. Then $n$ objects are randomly selected from $Z'$ objects. 

Will these 2 process still be the same? If not, under what condition will they be the same?

Comment: The goal of theses two approaches is the same: use one sample of $n$ objects to estimate some properties of the filtered objects (i.e, population of $Z$)

Comment: They're not precisely the same. Note that if you filter after sampling, you might have 0 things remaining in your collection. No conditions will make them be the same; in one scenario, you will have $n$ objects, and in the other, you will have fewer than $n$.

Comment: If I can assure more than $n$ objects are available after filtering in both approaches, will they be the same? 

My concern is, in the process of $N$ -> $Z$, and $k$-> $Z'$, $Z'$ may not be actually randomly selected, even if $k$ is randomly selected. I.e, the distribution of $k$ can be changed after filtering. I am not sure if my concern applies.

Comment: It depends very much on what your "filtering" process is, but at this level of generality, no, they can't be guaranteed to be the same. Example: take a population of 100 adults. Taking a random sample of 10 of them, then restricting to the top half of that, is different than taking the full 100, restricting to the top half, and sampling five from that.

Comment: I see. If the filtering process is a classification process, for example, adults above certain height. Can these two be the same? If I want these two approaches to be the same, what characteristics does the "filtering" process has to have? Thank you!

Comment: A sufficient, but maybe not necessary, condition: if each object can pass through the filter independently of other objects, and the sample sizes can be guaranteed to be the same, then the two methods should be equivalent. I don't think I can comment at this level of generality beyond that, and this line of inquiry probably deserves its own question.

Comment: Thank you Aaron!